# Loading Images within a Package

Tags: python, pygame, package

I've run into issues with `pygame` trying to load images when I imported my mainmenu file.
It's successful when I run it on its own, but when I import from the Main file I get an error as it tries to load the image:

```
"pygame.error: Couldn't open Resources/BKg.png"
```

This is my original loading code in mainmenu:

```
bkg = pygame.image.load("Resources/BKg.png").convert_alpha()
```

but then I modified it to the below, thinking the package layout might have been the issue, didn't work though.

```
bkg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Resources","BKg.png")).convert_alpha()
```

This is my file structure:

Project/

```
 Main.py ---------  start here, import Package.mainmenu, load Bkg.png FAILURE
 Package/
         mainmenu.py ------- start here, load Bkg.png SUCCESS
         Resources/
                   Bkg.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are loading from `Main.py` you need to do it like this:

```
bkg = pygame.image.load("Package/Resources/BKg.png").convert_alpha()
```

or

```
bkg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Package","Resources","BKg.png")).convert_alpha()
```

because yopure structure says `Resources` is in `Package`

just because you imported from the `Package` directory doesn't mean you can load images from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
bkg = pygame.image.load("Package/Resources/BKg.png").convert_alpha()
```